# Win32 disabling windows modal error dialogues when copying files

Tags: c, winapi

I am working at an OS independent file manager (using SDL). I am trying to use native functions as much as possible (with the appropriate #ifdefs), and I am having a problem with Windows. When I am using

```
CopyFileEx()
```

for example, if there is a problem it will pop up a modal dialogue, and the user will have to press some buttons to get rid of it. I want to handle the errors myself, in my programs, to make it less annoying.

**Is there any way to disable those modal windows?**

I noticed that if I start my application from a debugger (Insight) it will not display those messages.

Thanks in advance!

*P.S. The language I am using is plain C.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want the [`SetErrorMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: @Radu: Feel free to use the checkmark to the left of my answer (starts out as an outline, turns solid green when you click) to let others know that this solved your problem.  It gives me credit for a "best" answer, and improves your statistic on accepted answers, which shows other people that you follow up on your questions after asking them.

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows file manager SHFileOperation() is possible a better fit than CopyFileEx(). This will result in the native sheall dialogs for progress, conflict resolution etc. The levels of progress and error reporting can all be controlled.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. SHFileOperation() seems like a nice function, especially that it can also do rename and delete (which I will have to implement separately otherwise). On the downside, I will have to implement all those functions separately anyway for other OSes.

Comment: the big advantage is that the user sees native shell dialogs so your file manager feels integrated. Of course you may want dialogs with your own feel, dialogs so your file manager feels integrated. Of course you may want dialogs with your own feel,

Comment: Yes, the idea is that I made all my dialogues in SDL (manually). I know, I know... So I am trying to have all the dialogues have the same looks, and look the same on all the supported OSes (mainly Windows and Linux).